# CSS animation moves backwards after mid way

Tags: css, css-animations

I've got this simple animation where a box is supposed to slide in from left and slide out to right. But after half way point it starts moving backwards. Any ideas why?

```
h2{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0rem 1rem;
    color: black;
}
h2:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ff7c7c;
    z-index: -1;
    animation: title-highlight 1s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes title-highlight{
    0%{
        left: 0;
        right: 100%;
    }
    50%{
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    },
    100%{
        left: 100%;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing that one comma `,` inside the keyframe definition

Answer (score 0):

You can add an iteration count otherwise it will just loop.

```
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

I've edited your original example in snippet below.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #000;
      padding: 12px 24px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    h1 span {
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    h2{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0rem 1rem;
    color: black;
}
h2:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ff7c7c;
    z-index: -1;
    animation: title-highlight 1s linear forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
@keyframes title-highlight{
    0%{
        left: 0;
        right: 100%;
    }
    50%{
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    100%{
        left: 100%;
        right: 0;
    }
}

  </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>
      HELLO THERE
    </h2>

</body>

</html>
```